# Python urllib.urlopen IOError

Tags: python, urllib

So I have the following lines of code in a function

```
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = sock.read()
sock.close()
```

and they work fine when I call the function by hand.  However, when I call the function in a loop (using the same urls as earlier) I get the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./headlines.py", line 256, in <module>
    main(argv[1:])
  File "./headlines.py", line 37, in main
    write_articles(headline, output_folder + "articles_" + term +"/")
  File "./headlines.py", line 232, in write_articles
    print get_blogs(headline, 5)
  File "/Users/michaelnussbaum08/Documents/College/Sophmore_Year/Quarter_2/Innovation/Headlines/_code/get_content.py", line 41, in get_blogs
    sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 203, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 314, in open_http
    if not host: raise IOError, ('http error', 'no host given')
IOError: [Errno http error] no host given
```

Any ideas?

Edit more code:

```
def get_blogs(term, num_results):
    search_term = term.replace(" ", "+")
    print "search_term: " + search_term
    url = 'http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=en&q='+search_term+'&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss'
    print "url: " +url  

    #error occurs on line below

    sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = sock.read()
    sock.close()

def write_articles(headline, output_folder, num_articles=5):

    #calls get_blogs

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

    output_file = output_folder+headline.strip("\n")+".txt"
    f = open(output_file, 'a')
    articles = get_articles(headline, num_articles)
    blogs = get_blogs(headline, num_articles)


    #NEW FUNCTION
    #the loop that calls write_articles
    for term in trend_list: 
        if do_find_max == True:
        fill_search_term(term, output_folder)
    headlines = headline_process(term, output_folder, max_headlines, do_find_max)
    for headline in headlines:
    try:
        write_articles(headline, output_folder + "articles_" + term +"/")
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use urllib2 instead if you don't want to handle reading on a per block basis yourself.
This probably does what you expect.

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request(url='http://stackoverflow.com/')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print f.read()
```

Comment: Good idea but no luck, I get "urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>", both errors are saying no "no host", but I don't know why...

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when a variable I was concatenating with the url, in your case `search_term`

```
url = 'http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=en&q='+search_term+'&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss'
```

had a newline character at the end. So make sure you do

```
search_term = search_term.strip()
```

You might also want to do

```
search_term = urllib2.quote(search_term)
```

to make sure your string is safe for a url

Answer (score 1):

In your function's loop, right before the call to `urlopen`, perhaps put a print statement:

```
print(url)
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

This way, when you run the script and get the IOError, you will see the `url` which is causing the problem. The error "no host given" can be replicated if `url` equals something like `'http://'`...

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, for example one url is "http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=en&q=Iceland+Pictures+Lightning+Adds+Flash&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss". They are all search Google Blog Search with different queries. It works if I just call urlopen in the interpreter, or if I call the entire function that makes the url, but it doesn't work when I call it in a loop.

Comment: So does it always crash on the same query or difference ones?
Are you behind a web proxy?